# Jprofiler Jpcotroller to start and stop recording of JDBC connections

Tags: jprofiler

I have a simple question and that is whether it is possible to control **JProfiler** recording of JDBC connections from command line?

for CPU views I use JPController but it seems it doesn't support *jdbc* connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is supported in jcontroller as of JProfiler 8.1.